# Puta Value in a link

Tags: javascript

How do I get the value from "js-article number" in to this "value from js-article number"
Regards Stefan

```
var x=document.getElementById("js-articlenumber").innerText;


<a href="https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest_redirect.php?id=[value from js-articlenumber]&f=xxxxx" target="_blank"><img src="https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest.php?id=[value from js-articlenumber]&f=xxxxx" /></a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing href value from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200466/changing-href-value-from-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

You need two things.

1. a way to create the link based on the value of js-articlenumber:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
2. a way to change the href/src value.

so my suggestion would be:

```
var x=document.getElementById("js-articlenumber").innerText;
var link=`https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest_redirect.php?id=${x}&f=xxxxx`
var imageSrc=`https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest.php?id=${x}&f=xxxxx`
document.getElementById("PutAnIdOnTheATag").href=link; 
document.getElementById("PutAnIdOnTheImage").src=imageSrc;
```

Comment: Thanks :)
One more question. How do I print the new link on the page?
document.write?

Comment: * `console.log('something')` will print something on the dev tools console.
* if you want to see the value you can inspect the link (using the dev tools)
* if you want to write the string in an element: `selectedElement.innerHTML = link;`

document.write will replace all the markup with the arguments:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: "<a class='gotoLine' href='#54:49'>54:49</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of null"

Comment: You are going to need to put an id attribute on the a tag eg `<a id="someId">` and then replace the "PutAnIdOnTheTag" with the value you put. Beware ids should be unique so if you have more than one a tags you should have a different selector: https://www.tutsmake.com/javascript-get-element-by-id-name-class-tag-value/

Comment: Have done it. But nothing is displayed on the page.

<span id="js-articlenumber">LS0411536</span>

<a id="someId"></a>

<a id="someId1"></a>

var x=document.getElementById("js-articlenumber").innerTEXT;
var link=`https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest_redirect.php?id=${x}&f=33164`
var imageSrc=`https://instore.prisjakt.nu/cheapest.php?id=${x}&f=33164`
document.getElementById("someId").href=link; 
document.getElementById("someId1").src=imageSrc;

Comment: it's because innerTEXT should be innerText. You can try the code on your developer tools console.

Comment: I have test that and i have the code on https://jsfiddle.net/ Dont work

Comment: Now it works <a id="someId"><img src id="someId1"></a>